# PDF file generated in C# / ASP.NET MVC application can not be opened

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, pdf, pdf-generation

I have a C# ASP.NET MVC application which generates a `.pdf` file using the following code:

```
public ActionResult BuildPDF() 
{
    // <code executes to establish printdocs>>
    PdfFileEditor oEditor = new PdfFileEditor();
    oEditor.Concatenate(printdocs.ToArray(), printfinalStream);
    printfinalStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    return File(printfinalStream, "application/pdf", "Authorization_" + GetNewGuid() + ".pdf");
}
```

This code properly generates a `.pdf` file and returns it to the browser where is gets placed into the downloads folder.

Now, I need to return a text string along with the file so the text string can be alerted to the user when the process has completed.

This is what the new code looks like:

```
public ActionResult BuildPDF() 
{
    // <code executes to establish printdocs>>
    PdfFileEditor oEditor = new PdfFileEditor();
    oEditor.Concatenate(printdocs.ToArray(), printfinalStream);
    printfinalStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    var combinedData = new CombinedData
    {
        Text = msg,
        PdfData = printfinalStream.ToArray(), // Convert the MemoryStream to a byte array.
        FileName = "Authorization_" + GetNewGuid() + ".pdf"
    };

    return Json(combinedData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And this is what my Javascript looks like:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: '@Url.Action("PrintandEmailAuthorization", "Forms")',
   data: {
          "LetterDated": obj.LetterDated, "AuthDated": obj.AuthDated, "ReturnBy": obj.ReturnBy, "ProtestMonth": obj.ProtestMonth,
          "TaxYear": obj.TaxYear, "FromFileNum": obj.FromFileNum, "ToFileNum": obj.ToFileNum, "Suffix": obj.Suffix, "PaperSource": obj.PaperSource,
          "LetterSignedBy": obj.LetterSignedBy, "Title": obj.Title, "ConsentAttorney": obj.ConsentAttorney, "includeexemption": obj.Includeexemption,
          "includethirdrequest": obj.Includethirdrequest, "includeconsent": obj.Includeconsent, "includeref": obj.Includeref,
          "AttorneyName": obj.AttorneyName, "AttorneyEmail": obj.AttorneyEmail, "TemplateName": obj.TemplateName, "TemplatePath": obj.TemplatePath, "Enclosures": obj.Enclosures,
          "OldContingencyFee": obj.OldContingencyFee, "NewContingencyFee": obj.NewContingencyFee, "ContactID": obj.ContactID, "OptionSelected": obj.OptionSelected,
          "IncludeMultLotsRe": obj.IncludeMultLotsRe, "VillTaxYear": obj.VillTaxYear, "isTest": false
      },
      success: function (data) {
                alert(data.Text);
                // Create a Blob for the PDF data.
                var blob = new Blob([data.PdfData], { type: 'application/pdf' });

                // Create a temporary URL for the Blob.
                var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

                // Create a hidden anchor element to trigger the download.
                var a = document.createElement('a');
                a.style.display = 'none';
                a.href = url;
                a.download = data.FileName;
                document.body.appendChild(a);

                // Simulate a click on the anchor element to trigger the download.
                a.click();

                // Clean up the temporary URL and anchor element.
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                document.body.removeChild(a);
            }
        });
```

The process runs and I get the alert of the text message and the `.pdf` file does download but when I try to open the resulting `.pdf` I get an error telling me the data is corrupted.

I'm sure its a simple matter of converting `.pdf` data from the server to the client, but I'm not really sure.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: @KJ - I opened the correctly generated .pdf (when only a File was being returned to the browser) with Notepad.  The first line of the file is "%PDF-1.7".  Then I opened the bad file (created with the blob) with Notepad.  The first line of the file starts with "37,80,68,70,45,49,46,55,13,37,200,200,200".  So, data is not being added to the file.  Maybe its because I am executing a ToArray twice (once in the oEditor.Concatenate command and once when I create the combinedData object)?  I'll have to run some tests.

Comment: Amazing if it works!

Comment: @KJ - I ended up saving the generated .pdf to a server folder and returned an object back to the view with the text to display and the path/file name to the saved .pdf file. Then in the view, in the ajax success, I alert the text message and then do a windows.href back to the controller passing back the path/file name.  Then, the controller returns the file.  I also put in a timer so after 5 seconds, I return to the controller to delete the file from the server and return back to the view.  I know its a lot of back and forth but it accomplishes what I need to do.